# Question regarding languages and P

Tags: complexity-theory, regular-languages

According to [this Wikipedia article on unary language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/unary_language) every unary language has a binary variant. My question is that given a unary language is there an equivalent binary language in P that is P-Complete.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As said Yuval Filmus in the [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104899/question-regarding-languages-and-p#comment224243_104899), some unary languages are undecidable, so they don't even have an equivalent binary language in P.